# Programmatically obtain connection parameters to connected database in Excel Files

Tags: c#, excel, xml, ms-access, connection

- I have connected to data in an Access database file table
- I can see the path to the Access database file from within Excel's Advanced editor.
- I cannot find this information manually searching the xml files from the unzipped excel workbook file.

(btw, I created the connection via: Data (tab) -> Get and Transform Data (Section) -> Get Data (Button) -> From Database -> From Microsoft Access Database.

**How/Where is this Access database *file path* information stored?**

**How can I obtain(/edit) this *Access database file path* information programmatically; namely in C#?**

When unzipping the workbook, I cannot find the file path anywhere; for example: in xl/connections.xml there is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<connections xmlns:xr16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2017/revision16" mc:Ignorable="xr16" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<connection id="1" saveData="1" background="1" refreshedVersion="6" type="5" description="Connection to the 'Qry_PagesByProject' query in the workbook." name="Query - Qry_PagesByProject" keepAlive="1" xr16:uid="{97DDFE32-F190-4840-8AD9-C2456C0D5FAF}">
<dbPr command="SELECT * FROM [Qry_PagesByProject]" connection="Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Qry_PagesByProject;Extended Properties="""/>
</connection>
</connections>
```

...but no mention of the Access database file path.

- If I move the Access database file, the workbook then complains and cannot update the data in the worksheet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly how did you make the connection?

Comment: `xl/connections.xml` has the connection information

Comment: thanks @TimWilliams. There is no file path information there, or in any of the xml files, but Excel complains if I move it; moreover, when I  go to the "Advanced Editor" via the "Power Query Editor" I see the file path there! There is however a huge string of letters, numbers and symbols in customxml/item1.xml could this contain the information encoded?

Comment: OK - that sounds like Power Pivot (which I don't have installed).  I tested using "Data >> From Access"

Answer (score 0):

Crediting this to my work colleagues and their research and dev work:

*" Microsoft Excel 2016 has a new, built-in functionality called "Get & Transform". It is also known as PowerQuery.
 It suppports a) querying data from files, databases, web services & custom sources and b) transforming these.
 Also, because it can combine data from multiple sources, it is called Mashups. 
 While the user typically specifies this in easy to use user interface, the source, query and transformations
 are stored in form of a new programming language called M."*

We have found the filepath in the form of 'M', and encoded in `customxml/item1.xml`, and we can obtain and edit it programmatically.